# homogeneous differential equations understanding example $(y-x)y'=2x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading an example on homogeneous differential equations which goes like this:

$$
(y-x)y'=2x
$$

Understand that in those case of scenarios we let $$y=y(x)=xz(x)$$
After we differentiate we get
$$y'=z+xz'=\frac{2}{z-1}$$

I really don't understand why $z+xz'=\frac{2}{z-1}$. How did we get that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually really simple.
$$ z+xz'=y'=\frac{2x}{y-x} = \frac{2}{\frac{y}{x}-1} = \frac{2}{z-1} $$
Because for non-zero $x$
$$ y = xz \iff z=\frac{y}{x} $$

Answer (score 1):

$$(y-x)y'=2x \implies y'= \frac {2x}{y-x} = \frac {2}{y/x-1}=\frac {2}{z-1}$$

$$ y= xz \implies y' = xz' + z$$

$$ xz' + z =\frac {2}{z-1}$$

$$xz'  =\frac {2}{z-1}- z$$

which is separable.

Comment: Take common denominator on the right side and separate variables, then partial fraction and integrate to get  an equation in z and x, then back substitute  y/x for z to get an implicit solution in y and x.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x\neq 0$, which excludes $y= x\iff z=1$. Then you have  $y'=2x/(y-x)$ and $y=xz$, then$$
y'= 2x/(xz-x)=2/(z-1),
$$
and you can conclude with the identity $y'=z+xz'$.